iOS [React Native / Swift] make local HTTP request
I'm developing in react native and I need to connect my app to my printer which is on the same local network. For that, I have made a bridge in swift and I'm using NWConnection(ip:port) to connect to my printer.
connection = NWConnection.init(
    host: NWEndpoint.Host(ip),
    port: NWEndpoint.Port("\(port)")!,
    using: params
)
...
self.connection!.start(queue: queue)

It works well in debug but not in release mode because apple doesn't permit to connect via http.
So I have tried to make a simple request to my printer via fetch (RN)
const onPing = () => {
    fetch('http://192.168.1.17:9100')
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.status === 200) {
                console.log('success')
            } else {
              console.log('error')
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('network error: ' + error)
        })
}

and same problem, it works in debug but not in release. (this endpoint http://192.168.1.17:9100 prints something in my web navigator)
I have a lot of permissions in my Info.plist
<key>NSBonjourServices</key>
<array>
    <string>_printer._tcp.</string>
    <string>_bonjour._tcp.</string>
    <string>_lnp._tcp.</string>
</array>
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAllowsLocalNetworking</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>192.168.1.17</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
<key>NSLocalNetworkUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs a network access to connect to printers on the same network</string>
<key>NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription</key>
<string>Need to use your bluetooth to detect printers around</string>
<key>NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Need to use your bluetooth to detect printers around</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string></string>

So my question is, how can I request my local network via HTTP in iOS release mode? (not https)
I'm on an ipad  with iOS 17.6.1 and my Rn version is 0.71.7
fetch http => should works on iOS release mode with the allowed permissions

you should check this similiar question: How to Make HTTP Requests In React Native IOS application?
